# CodeIgniter removing index.php from base url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am working with CodeIgniter under LAMPP stack.

i have the following set as my baseurl

```
http://example.com/subfolder
```

This is my folder structure

```
root
 |
 |
ci_engine
public_html
 |
 |----subfolder
 |     |
 |     |
 |     |------applications, index.php, .htaccess
public_ftp
 |
 |
other_stuff
```

The following is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

If i type `http://example.com/subfolder/controller/function`

If i type `http://example.com/subfolder/index.php?/controller/function` << this works like a charm.

I would get 404 error.

How should i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Heres htaccess for you

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

and set

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Use `sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo service apache2 restart` to enable your mod rewrite if its not enabled (Ubuntu).

`Options -Indexes` is optional (Just to avoid directory listing)

Answer (score 0):

You can change index.html from

```
application/config/rought.php
```

in this page you found

```
$route['default_controller'] = "content/pages";
```

Change to

```
$route['default_controller'] = "";
```